# How to correctly use QOpenGLBuffer's allocate/read/write in PyQt5?

Tags: python, pyqt5

[This](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qopenglbuffer.html#allocate) requires a void * data input. So, I got it working with something like this,

```
vbo = QtGui.QOpenGLBuffer(QtGui.QOpenGLBuffer.VertexBuffer)
vrtxAttrs = [1., 1., 1., 0., 0.1, 0.1, 1.0,
             -1., -1., -1., 1.0, 0.9, 0.9, 1.0] # a list of interleaved positions xyz and colors rgba
data = numpy.array(vrtxAttrs, dtype=numpy.float32)
```

I will be honest, I don't know how I got here. I tried numerous things and stumbled upon using `data.ctypes.data_as(ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_void_p)).contents`. Please tell me this is awful and there is a better way to do it.

```
# How I allocate..
vbo.allocate(data.ctypes.data_as(ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_void_p)).contents,
                          sys.getsizeof(data))
```

```
# How I write.. (I believe this calls glBufferSubData internally)
# I intend to change the second vertex's position and color.
newdata = [2., 2., 2., 0.5, 0.4, 0.4, 1.]
toWrite = numpy.array(newdata, dtype=numpy.float32)
offset = 1 * 7 * 4 # this has to be in bytes. (1 is the index, 7 the stride, 4 the bytesize.)
count = len(newdata) * 4 # this has to be in bytes.
vbo.write(offset, data.ctypes.data_as(ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_void_p)).contents, count)
```

```
# How I read,
# I don't read, since I don't know what weird cast I need to do to read.
# The usage is documented as bool QOpenGLBuffer::read(int offset, void *data, int count)
```

The python documentation for these are ridiculous, yeah we know how to use them in C++, what about python? For starters, I am looking for answers that explain [sip.voidptr](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/gotchas.html#support-for-void)

Comment: Hmm... This is the first time I've seen someone use PyQt and end up with more complexity compared to using C++ in the first place. Should be a prize for that! 

Comment: Something you're missing in my answer? You know, the bounty and all... Must choose my answer as "the solution" to get it shipped my way. Time is up now, but I guess "the system" (SO) is smart enough to figure out that it was about 3 hours left when I answered once it gets accepted. But I tend to overestimate the intelligence of both people and the computer systems created by them people.

Comment: I was very puzzled and clueless about getting this to working in python. I've been monitoring this post for days like a zombie and not a single answer. I gave up about 2 days back. Heck, I even dreamt that someone commented to use lists. That made me check the post today. Thanks, kind stranger!

Comment: Haha, so there are people out there that's even more nuts than myself! 

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably won't win any prizes with this answer, it is done in a hurry at 04:00 AM.

I don't get exactly what you're trying to do from your code, but from what I can understand, the question is how to use allocate/read/write in the context of a QOpenGLBuffer for dealing with a NumPy array?

```py
# Your imports / initializer code here...

buffer = QOpenGLBuffer(QOpenGLBuffer.VertexBuffer)
buffer.create() #Creates the buffer object in the OpenGL server
buffer.bind()   # Binds object to the current OpenGL context
buffer.allocate(120) # How many bytes to allocate

data = numpy.array([2., 2., 2., 0.5, 0.4, 0.4, 1.], dtype = numpy.float32).toString()

# Write
buffer.write(0, data, len(data))
# Release buffer
buffer.release()
```

The read method is like the write method, it takes `buffer.read(offset, data, count)`. The C++ signature is read(int offset, void *data, int count), but the PyQt implementation abstracts this to read(offset, data, count).

It does assume that the buffer is bound to the current OpenGL context.

Comment: THIS IS IT! I apologize, I didn't read the answer until now. I accepted the answer though